# Enable hyperlinks for "see" in indexing?

Tags: hyperref, indexing, imakeidx

I'm currently using packages `hyperref` and `imakeidx` to create my book's index. This index is big enough that it spans multiple pages. It contains some entries such as

```
% In the index under "B"...

\index{bar!foo|see {foobar}}%

% Several pages later in the index, under "F"...

\index{foobar}%
```

Since I'm using package `hyperref`, index-entries that point to a specific page in the mainmatter are rendered as hyperlinks in the final PDF. I wonder if there is a way to hyperlink the *see* entries as well. That is, I'd like to render "bar, *see* foobar" as a hyperlink that points to the page of the index where "foobar" is listed.

Is this possible? and if so, what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

A preliminary version, working for top-level index items only, not working for entries like `bar!foo` itself if `|see {foo}` is meant.

There is a hypertarget defined and retrieved with `\seelink`.

The multiple usage of `\index{foobar}` will prevent same target names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\AtBeginDocument{%

  \LetLtxMacro\indexorig\index

  \newcommand{\hyperindextarget}[1]{%
    \hypertarget{#1}{}%
  }

  \RenewDocumentCommand{\index}{om}{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}{%
      \addindextarget[#1]{#2}%
    }{%
      \addindextarget{#2}%
    }%
  }
}

\newcommand{\seelink}[2]{%
  \seename\ \hyperlink{#1}{#1}%
}


\seq_new:N \g_quuxxplusone_target_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\addindextarget}{om}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_quuxxplusone_target_seq {#2} {%
      \indexorig[#1]{#2}%
    }{% False branch
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_quuxxplusone_target_seq {#2}
      \indexorig[#1]{#2|hyperindextarget{#2}}%
    }%
  }{% No optional argument
    \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_quuxxplusone_target_seq {#2} {%
      \indexorig{#2}%
    }{% False branch
      \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_quuxxplusone_target_seq {#2}
      \indexorig{#2|hyperindextarget{#2}}%
    }%
  }%    
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeindex


\begin{document}



Foo
\clearpage
\blindtext[5]
% In the index under "B"...

\index{bar}
\index{bar!foo|seelink {foobar}}%

% Several pages later in the index, under "F"...

\blindtext[15]

\index{foobar}%

\blindtext[15]

\index{foobar}

\index{zzz|seelink{bar}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll try to improve this as soon as possible

Comment: Hi Christian. My vote is always +1.